# Incoming call notification volume control stream

Tags: android, notifications, volume

I use a full screen notification for an incoming call and play a ringtone by using the following:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
        .setSound(RingToneUtils.getDefaultRingtoneURI(), AudioManager.STREAM_RING)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setLights(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 255), 300, 300)
        .addAction(iconAction1, action1, answerActionPendingIntent)
        .addAction(iconAction2, action2, rejectActionPendingIntent)
        .setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);
```

This works fine and displays as a HUD when appropriate. The problem is that the ring tone audio volume is controlled by the notification volume stream and not the ring tone volume stream.

How can this be corrected to the ring tone stream? Technically it IS a notification but to the user this seems wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for something like play ring tone for notification?

Comment: No, it plays the ring tone as you can see in the .setSound() line. I want to control the volume with ring volume and not notification volume, because it is a ring tone not a notification tone

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust Notification Sound using `AudioManager` like this:

```
    AudioManager mgr=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);
```

you can set volume for notification sound from 0 to 10. Hope this will help.